# MongoDB query for a tree structure to return children whose parents have specific attributes

Tags: mongodb

I'm new to Mongo and would love some help!

I have a [Parent References](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/model-tree-structures-with-parent-references/) tree structure which looks like this:

```
Object {
    _id: <some id>
    parent: <an _id or null if topmost>
    allowed : [userIds]
}
```

I'd like a query that returns all objects whose topmost parent has this user id in the allowed list. The topmost parent is the one whose parent is null, and the topmost parent should also be returned as part of the query.

Typically, a tree will have 1-10 levels but could be more. Should I be worried about performance?

Comment: You would need to store the ancestors in each object to make your query work, or use a map reduce.

Comment: Storing one additional field per object to specify the topmost parent would be fine. How would a query look if I did that?

Comment: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/model-tree-structures/

Comment: Thanks, I've seen this and have even linked it above in my post, but it has a description of what Parent References are not how to do the query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've figured it out, for whomever needs this. You have to do two queries basically:

```
    // 1 - GET THE ANCESTORS
    var allowedAncestorIds = [];
    Objects.find({
        parent: null,
        allowed: this.userId
    }).forEach(function (ancestor) {
        // 2 - STORE THEIR IDs
        allowedAncestorIds.push(ancestor._id);
    });

    return Objects.find({
        $or: [
            // 3 - USE THE ALLOWED ANCESTOR IDs IN THE QUERY TO GET ALL THE OBJECTS
            {parent: {$in: allowedAncestorIds}},
            {allowed: this.userId}
        ]
    });
```